# What can I use as acoustical caulk?

Tags: drywall, sound-proofing

I am installing a plaster board ceiling for sound proofing a room.
I left a 5mm gap between the plasterboard and the wall to allow it to vibrate.

I know I have to fill it with some kind of caulk. I find many references to acoustical caulk on the Internet but none at my local construction depot.

I need to finish this so ordering from the Internet is not an option either.

What is the substance used in acoustical caulk?
What can I use as an acoustical caulk?

It needs to stay flexible, paintable and have an effective isolation.

Comment: i've not heard of such a product, but the mu of regular caulk should suffice.

Comment: Can you send a link? is it paintable? if it's silicone based it can't be.

Comment: i don't know about the logistics, only the physics of dense rubbery materials...